# QFile.atEnd() returns TRUE too early

Tags: eof, qfile

I'm trying to read in a CSV file. My code is below. The problem I am having is that the first line of the file is read in, as expected, but once the while loop condition is reached again File.atEnd returns true. I've tried this with several files, some very large, and it still only reads the first line of the CSV file. I've stepped through with the debugger and cannot find a reason why this is so.
Running Win7 Pro (64-bit)
Qt v5.0.1 (32-bit)
QDesigner v2.6.2.

UPDATE: If I have a CSV file with a lot of columns than it seems to work out.

```
QFile File(strFileName);
File.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);

QTextStream FileStream(&File);

while( !File.atEnd() )
{
    QString strLine = FileStream.readLine();
    //Do some code here
}

File.close();
```

Example CSV file:

```
1,10,20
2,20,30
3,30,40
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
while( !File.atEnd() )
```

to

```
while( !FileStream.atEnd() )
```